# Can users repay transaction when the status of PaymentDetails is ERROR?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Users of my app can create and pay transaction via AdaptivePayments API.

In various cases the transactions ended up being in ERROR status (so the request for PaymentDetails says). What can be the cause of this?

And is the user then able to retry the payment of this transaction with the same paykey or is it necessary to create a completely new transaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the return of the "ERROR" status can be determined from when you originally submitted the API call. You would have received a failure notice with an error code and an actual error message.

You can't retry the payment, unfortunately. If the "ERROR" was caused by a decline the sender would need to update their funding source or address whatever caused the decline but you wouldn't be able to try and complete it again with the same paykey.